# implementing autocorrect affecting another application

Tags: android, autocomplete, autosuggest, google-suggest

I saw many posts about making the autocomplete to the current autocomplete text view
but I need to make the autocomplete to another application

for example , I want to use my program/service to write inside skype or facebook or browser

how can I implement that

please explain to me with very basic

Comment: You'd probably need to implement a custom input method to do that.

Comment: how ? can you tell me in more details please ? I'm quite new to android

Comment: Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: @Philio I tried that link and I see only titles , even the sample referred doesn't show me how to make my own keyboard,  for example I faced at least the following troubles I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078460/how-i-create-my-own-input-method